# Out of memory when uploading an image in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting an 'out of memory' error message when I try to upload a file in WordPress. The file I'm trying to upload is an image ~1.6mb in file size and about 2500 x 2500 in dimensions. I'm using the [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) plugin to do the uploading. The plugin uses the WP function [wp_handle_upload()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload). The specific error message I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 84410368) (tried to allocate
>   9792 bytes) in wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php on line 339.

My aim is to pinpoint what exactly is 'out of memory'. Would this be my server out of memory? Or would this be the client? e.g. the user's browser? One thing I have noticed which *might* be important is that I can upload without problems if I use my laptop or iPad yet I always experience the error if I use my iPhone or my netbook.

I'd be grateful for any pointers you may have so that I can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One thing I have noticed which might be important is that I can upload
>   without problems if I use my laptop or iPad yet I always experience
>   the error if I use my iPhone or my netbook.

That's really just a coincidence.

But running out of memory when WordPress activates a plugin or you do a large image upload is fairly common.

Try increasing the memory for PHP and Wordpress in several different ways:

1) You can edit the memory_limit line in your php.ini (if you have access to that file) to increase memory to 64M:

`memory_limit = 64M;`

2) Try adding the "define" line below in your [wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) file a few lines of white space below the opening  `<?php` in the file:

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

3) If those don't work, try adding this line at the top of your .htaccess file:

`php_value memory_limit 64M`

If that doesn't work or throws a "500 Internal Server Error", delete the line from .htaccess.

*If none of those work, your host probably doesn't allow memory allocation overrides. You're stuck with what they give.*

You can run phpinfo to see what kind of memory allocation you already have. Make a plain text file and call it `phpinfo.php` and put just this line in it:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

then put the file in the root of your server, and then go to that file with your web browser. You'l see all the php info you need; scroll down for memory settings. If you get an error, that means your web hosting company won't allow phpinfo to run for security reasons.

Comment: I didn't have access to the php.ini file so created a new one and set the `memory_limit` to 256M. Defining `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M'` also seemed to be necessary. The .htaccess solution did in fact cause a 500 Internal Server Error. `phpinfo()` was helpful too - it let me check the changes I made to the memory limit worked.

Comment: one thing you didn't mention was the `MaxRequestLen` setting. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698474/1709033 for more info. Could this be the problem do you think?

Comment: @henrywright: the OP isn't showing an http error, and the answer has been accepted by the OP, so it probably worked.

Comment: Hi @songdogtech - Regarding your solution - it worked, thanks very much! However, I seem to be getting the HTTP error also - it appears on the screen when I use the WordPress media uploader in the WP admin area. Maybe that's a different issue to the memory issues I've highlighted in my question? apologies if that's the case

Comment: I think this could be a different issue to the 'out of memory' error in my original question so I've created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343691/http-error-when-uploading-an-image-via-the-wordpress-media-uploader - thanks for your help with my original problem

Answer (score 2):

This is a server-side restriction, not the client / browser.

Your web hoster has restrictions on PHPs memory limit, specifically the PHP INI setting `memory_limit`. There is nothing that you can do, you will need to contact your web hoster and inquire if the limit can be increased.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: I was thinking the same but the thing that threw me into doubt was the fact that uploads work fine on my laptop and iPad - yet I always get the error on my less powerful iPhone and netbook. If this was a server memory issue then wouldn't I get the error on all devices I try to upload with?

Comment: Also, the error message says tried to allocate '9792' bytes which is way below the '84410368' bytes allocated. I don't get it?