# HTTP error when uploading an image via the WordPress Media Uploader

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Each time I try to upload an image using the WordPress Media Uploader (WP Admin > Media > Add new) the upload stalls at around 13% and I get an error message appear on screen `"HTTP error"`.

So far I have created a php.ini file in my WordPress root with the following:

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
post_max_size = 64M
```

I've also put a php.ini file in my /wp-admin/ folder (an exact duplicate of the above).

After checking with `phpinfo()` I can see these changes have taken effect but they have not resolved the 'HTTP error' problem I am getting.

I am using a 1and1.co.uk dedicated server (managed) so don't have root access. 1and1 have confirmed plain CGI is enabled on the server (not Fast CGI if that makes much difference?).

Why might this error be happening? Is there anything else I can do to try to resolve it?

**UPDATE:** I have done some testing using different browsers and different devices:

Acer Aspire One netbook

- Chrome ***- problem exists***
- FireFox ***- problem exists***
- IE *- working*
- Safari ***- problem exists***

Acer Aspire 5552 laptop

- Chrome *- working*
- FireFox *- working*
- IE *- working*
- Safari *- working*

Google Nexus 7 tablet

- Chrome *- working*
- FireFox *- working*
- IE *- working*
- Safari *- working*

Samsung Galaxy G4 Mini

- Chrome *- working*
- FireFox *- working*
- IE *- working*
- Safari *- working*

As you can see the problem only exists in Chrome, FF and Safari on my Acer Aspire One netbook. What could be the source of this problem?

Comment: You may get a bit more help in the [Wordpress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/48335/) section of Stack Exchange.

Comment: try checking the permissions on the uploads directory.

Comment: Thanks Brandon but I'm not entirely sure the problem is specific to WordPress. for example, it could be server config related

Comment: As Khalid already suggested, try checking `uploads` directory permissions first

Comment: @KhalidDabjan permissions are fine. I've tested with 777 and still see the problem

Comment: Anything in the apache logs?

Comment: Does the debug console reveal anything about the error. Looks to be a issue related to the computer somehow

Comment: @Jono20201 checked the Apache logs... nothing.

Comment: @RonniSkansing the console logs are empty. Agreed the problem looks client related - why would I see the problem on just FF, Chrome and Safari on my Acer netbook? IE on the netbook _works_!!

Comment: @henrywright it is pretty strange none the less, but maybe the browser versions are different on that computer. Check out this link  http://jonrwilson.com/2009/12/wordpress-http-error-crunching-htaccess/

Comment: @RonniSkansing looking at the thread, I can see in Nginx there's `client_max_body_size` which sounds about right. Problem is I'm using Apache

Comment: @RonniSkansing I did checked the browser versions before I ran the tests. Updated all of them to the latest versions

Answer (score 10):

I put the following code into my functions.php file. It works!

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );
function change_graphic_lib($array) {
return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

Comment: For anyone lurking, this function also works well for me.

Comment: Very nice, this function worked for me also. Good work!

Comment: Could you explain why it works?  What is it forcing Wordpress to do that it doesn't do by default?

Comment: You should explain what this does. For those looking for an explanation : There are usually two image handling librairies installed with PHP which are GD and Image Magick. By default, WordPress uses Image Magick, but it seems this one has problems or configuration problems when on PHP 7.

Untill it is worked out, simply place this bit of code (up there in Ganesh's answer) and it will use GD instead of Image Magick.

Answer (score 1):

I have often had problems with the (IMHO) very finicky media uploader of WordPress. And almost without fail, they are jpegs. And I can almost always solve the problem by opening them in Photoshop and using the "Save for web..." command which, among other things, removes embedded icon previews and performs other optimizations. For some reason, that almost always works for me. Which leads me to believe that there is something in the files themselves that WordPress is choking on, not always related to size (although that can sometimes be a problem).

Comment: WordPress may well be choking on something. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Could be EXIF or other embedded data in the files...Are they jpgs in your case? Have you tried opening them in an image editor, re-saving them, and re-uploading the new images?

Comment: and looking at your test configs above, i am tempted to say that some combo of file contents and the way the file bits looked to the server while being streamed over the network during upload could have something to do with it. But that is a bit of a wild guess really. :)

Comment: Tried that, and tried with various different images taken on different cameras and even with some images downloaded from the net. I'm puzzled!

Comment: any idea why uploads are failing on the netbook only? Maybe it is related to the netbook's security software? i'm almost out of ideas..?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit at a loss in your case as well...Seems like something  on the netbook is modifying the stream of data on the way out...

Comment: Same issue here, some jpegs upload, most fail. Using browser uploader, through Firefox. The Photoshop resaved images (through Save for web) DON'T work 100% of the time. The file size does not make a difference, a 7Kb file from Photoshop failed, but 500kb jpeg sent by a client did not. Yes, I am guessing metadata in combination with the browser version.

Answer (score 1):

Put below code in your activated theme's functions.php file.

If your media uploader gives HTTP error while uploading image, Try to change graphic library using below filter.

Below filter used for change the graphic library.

I hope it's help you.

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

Comment: Hi Mr HK, welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your answer. Code only answers are discouraged as they don't teach the OP (or others coming across this) _why_ the code actually works. Could you edit your answer to explain your solution? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try a smaller image - both file size and display size - and see if you can upload it.

`mod_security` might be causing problems. Disable it to see if that is the problem.

Make an .htaccess file in your wp-admin directory. Add this to it:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried a tiny image 2.21kb with dimensions 117px by 50px. That worked! The image that fails is slightly bigger in file size but still not huge at 1.2mb. The dimensions are about 2500 x 1900. Regarding `mod_security` - I tried creating the .htaccess file in /wp-admin/ but that seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Ask your host; they have some internal php limits. Who is the host?

Comment: 1&1.co.uk - I've spoke to them a few times over the past few days. They're not very good with suggestions actually. And the trouble is I have little idea what to ask them as my server knowledge is very basic. I did ask them if `MaxRequestLen` could be increased (see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698474/1709033)? They said I could do that via the php.ini file but I seriously doubt php.ini is where you'd make that sort of config change

Comment: 1&1 is a junk host. That's the whole issue. Find someone else. You don't have acces to that level of the server to change MaxRequestLen.

Comment: I'm beginning to realise that about 1&1. Until now, I haven't needed to contact their dedicated server support team. I find them to be quite uninterested in helping unless the problem is ultra trivial. Thankfully there's sites like SO around :)

Comment: I just thought of something: is the php.ini file recursive? I have it in the WordPress root. should I put a copy in another folder? not entirely sure which folder though? And should I be using a 'full' php.ini file with everything in it or can I use a php.ini file with just the 3 statements?

Comment: OK, if you're on a dedicated server, you do need to jump into server admin. This is a completely different animal. You need to configure php to allow php.ini files in directories, or they won't be read. This could be security or possibly MaxLenRequests.

Comment: I tested if my php.ini file was being read using `phpinfo()` - it does seem to be as I can see the value of `memory_limit` has changed to 256M (the default was 120M).

Comment: I've just finished a round of cross-browser testing (please see my updated question) - it's interesting that the problem exists only in Chrome, FF and Safari on my Acer netbook

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser issue. WordPress media uploader uses JavaScript and it seems that some of the browsers you tested don't work well with such uploader.

You always have a link on add new media page to a non-javascript upload. Test that and see if the problem persists.

## Updated

We commented my first idea, and it isn't a browser issue.

So, if it's something related to the backend, I guess you should start checking type and size of images. Access to server logs should help you a lot.

Using Apache, directive `MaxRequestLen` is always an important factor. Did you check that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggest @grosshat. I doubt this is a JavaScript issue because the same problem is occurring with and without JavaScript enabled in the browser.

Comment: @henrywright Did you test the simple media uploader, thought for non-multiple files? The link is on the same media page.

Comment: Yes, I did test that too. Actually about 8 or 9 times :( No luck

Answer (score 0):

Just install plugin from here https://github.com/getsource/default-to-gd, and forget the error.

Comment: Can I ask why it's a good idea to set GD as the default image editor?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Hiawatha web server](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/), and in my case, the issue was `MaxRequestSize` and `MaxUploadSize` values being set too small.

I've solved it by adding this to my `/etc/hiawatha/hiawatha.conf`:

```
Binding {
        Port = 80
        MaxRequestSize = 1000000
        MaxUploadSize = 550
}
Binding {
        Port = 443
        SSLcertFile = /etc/hiawatha/serverkey.pem
        MaxRequestSize = 1000000
        MaxUploadSize = 550
}
```

Comment: Why 1000000KB for MaxRequestSize? That's about 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

it easy to fix. just click right button in picture, properties and than unblock picture, its on the bottom. that will work. I tried all other thinks from forums and nothing. works on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where any files over 100k were failing. The following worked for me:

Add the following line to fcgid.conf:

> FcgidMaxRequestLen 52428800

Answer (score 0):

Put this is your themes function.php It's Working.

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this: Upload the big images (using FTP or CPanel) to `wordpress folder/wp-content/uploads/2013` or something like this.

Then try to add these images to your wordpress site (post featured image/product image or others). You'll find the images at the left side under "uploaded images or all images".

Answer (score -2):

Try to edit link. in my case, it solve with changing name. Initially it is "webpic'1_1.jpg" and i removed " ' " and changed to "webpic1_1.jpg". It worked !...