# Wordpress http error

Tags: php, wordpress, file, http, upload

I have a problem with uploading files in wordpres 4.0.1. I want to upload a video over 40 mb, but gives error HTTP Error (net :: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED). I read all the topics here and what I did was to put maximum upload file to be 250 mb. in htaccess and php.ini files, also edit wp-config file. But still can not upload file. I noticed that I can upload files up to 40 Mb. If file is bigger than 40mb i get http error. Is it possible the problem to be connected with host server, not wordpress?

Thank you for your attention!  Will forward recommendations

Comment: can you upload it via ftp?

Comment: Yes i can upload file via ftp

Comment: if its shared hosting, contact the hosting provider, they usually set these things so you cant override them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress: "HTTP Error." When Uploading Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091063/wordpress-http-error-when-uploading-files)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to change the maximum upload size in your `.htaccess` file:

```
upload_max_filesize = "250M"
post_max_size = "250M"
```

If this doesn't work, you will probably need to contact/change your host.

Comment: When i put your code in htaccess i get "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: I use that code:
php_value upload_max_filesize 250M
php_value post_max_size = 250M
in htacces file, but still doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like your host doesn't allow you to change that. You may be out of luck without switching to a different one.

Comment: My host assured that the problem is not in them. And all settings are enough to upload large files. They advised me to check wordpres settings

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've fixed it by now, but having just solved this issue for myself, using a method I haven't seen elsewhere, let me share my solution.

I did all of the php.ini, .htaccess and wp-config hacks that everyone recommends.  Still, it didn't work.  Trying different file sizes, I eventually got not the Wordpress error, but an Nginx '504 Gateway Timeout' error page, which led me to my Nginx config.  I added the following two lines in the http section:

```
http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    client_body_timeout 300s;
    client_max_body_size 250m;
```

After that, I did a

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

and everything worked as it should have.

(To be fair, all of the .htaccess and php.ini stuff is probably necessary as well, so if this alone doesn't fix your issue, try them all.)

Hope this helps. It was a frustrating problem.