# -200, Message: HTTP Error

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to upload an image with wordpress am getting this error. It always uploads to 100% and the error displays.

```
picture_3.png (542 kb) 100%
Error: -200, Message: HTTP Error., File: picture_3.png
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress: "HTTP Error." When Uploading Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091063/wordpress-http-error-when-uploading-files)

Comment: Do you see any errors on server side? Logfile of PHP, Apache...

Answer (score 0):

Put this is your themes function.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

function change_graphic_lib($array) {
return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```